# Matlab Neural Network training doesn't yield good results

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to use a neural network for a classification problem, but the result of the training produce very bad performance. The classification problem:

- I have more than 300,000 training samples
- Each input is a vector of 32 values (real values)
- Each output is a vector of 32 values (0 or 1)

This is how I train the network:

```
DNN_SIZE = [1000, 1000];
% Initialize DNN
net = feedforwardnet(DNN_SIZE, 'traingda');
net.performParam.regularization = 0.2;
%Set activation functions
for i=1:length(DNN_SIZE)
    net.layers{i}.transferFcn = 'poslin';
end
net.layers{end}.transferFcn = 'logsig';

net = train(net, train_inputs, train_outputs);
```

- Note: I have tried different values for DNN_SIZE including larger and smaller values, for hidden layers and less, but it didn't make a difference.
- Note 2: I have tried training the same network using a data set from Matlab's examples (simpleclass_dataset) and I still got bad performance.

The performance of the trained network is very bad- Its output is basically 0.5 in every output for every input vector (when the target outputs during training are always 0 or 1). What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your target vector a one-hot vector, i.e. is only one of the entries 1, or can multiple entries be 1 at the same time?

Comment: @hbaderts my target is not a one-hot vector. it is a vector composed out out zeros and ones and any combination of them is possible.

Comment: Have you tried Matlab's official examples like : [OneExample](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/character-recognition.html?searchHighlight=neural%20network) and do they work bad? If so, you've found a bug; If not, perhaps you would have to re examine its usage.

Comment: @Chiron I don't think it's a bug. If I copy the exact code and network from matlab and run it on the exact data it works like in the Matlab examples. The problem is that my requirements are a bit different, and even if I change the network a little bit it doesn't work well. I want to know what am I doing wrong, so I can fix it...

Comment: In most cases, when I encountered a problem I would check data format firstly for preprocessing faults, then check if the method I selected is not the right one. e.g. When using euclidean distance for Text data, the precision I've got is 0.7. But 0.998 when using cosine. Same thing may happen to other kernels and activation functions.